# Chrome adds padding to DIVs with borders

Tags: css, google-chrome

I know this has been asked before and no one has ever solved it so it's fair to ask again and that it's fine in Firefox but any DIV with a border has unwanted padding so DIVs with borders can never perfectly touch in Chrome. It's absolutely fine in Firefox and even IE. Does anyone have any ideas?

```css
body, html {
    background-color: black;
}

.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 10px solid white;
}

.inner {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Here's Chrome based browsers adding a border.
[image: The snippet with Chrome adding a border]

Here it is completely fine in Firefox with no gaps.
[image: It's gapless in Firefox]

I've added just the code as its own page, the issue persists. The only styles applied are the ones shown.
[image: Just the code]

`EDIT` Why has this been closed? It's a known issue, that I've given a minimum reproducible example for.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of actual HTML code that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that shouldn't actually be necessary because I've explained a common issue. Will update.

Comment: The problem doesn't occur for me. When I run the Stack Snippet in Chrome, it looks like the screenshot you posted of running it in Firefox. Are you sure you don't have an extension or user script causing the problem?

Comment: I've tested it on a clean install of Chrome, Chrome beta and canary. All show it the same. Try expanding the snippet.

Comment: I just tried with Windows, macOS, Linux, Android, and Chrome OS, and both with and without expanding the snippet on all of them. None of them had the problem for me.

Comment: Works completely fine for me on both FF and chromium

Comment: Snippet working for me in Chrome 99

Comment: If you inspect the `.inner` in a Chromium browser does it say which styles are being applied? You can check the "Computed" tab to find out.

Comment: @cam They're the only styles included.

Comment: This question should be re-closed. Contrary to the asker's claim, the example provided is not reproducible. I tried myself to reproduce it using said example, and so did two other commenters, all unsuccessfully.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica it is reproducible and people on the chrome team have managed to do so. I was asking here for a workaround while I wait for the issue with chromium and blink to fix this.

Comment: Can you link to a Chromium bug report or something, then?

Answer (score 0):

I get similar behaviour when chrome is zoomed in. (chrome 103 on osx)
Codepen: https://codepen.io/ankedsgn/pen/YzaLXej

Lookes good on chrome and on FF, but when you zoom in on chrome, a padding on the image appears. See codepen on chrome, zoom in, and toggle the border to see the image grow and shrink.

code:

```
.visual {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  &__inner {
    border: 3px solid teal;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
}
```